# Can a server be configured to disable Self Signed Certificates?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, self-signed

I'm working on a project where I need to make REST calls through HTTPS. Is there a possibility that the Web service host server has disabled Self Signed certificates? thanks cod your ideas. I'm using Spring, Apache HttpClient for my project.

Comment: Spring should prevent it by default. Have you tried?

Comment: Hi @vahdet, I assume you mean Spring Security?